# Setting custom attribute name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

using vue.js, is it possible to set a custom attribute name, instead of attribute value? the below code doesn't seem to work. it will render the mustache

pseudo code:

```
<template v-for="item in list">

    <div myattr{{item.name}}="something">{{item.desc}}</div>

</template>
```

any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [custom directive](https://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html)

**HTML**:

```
<div id="app">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <div v-set-attribute="item">{{item.desc}}</div>
  </li>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
Vue.directive('set-attribute', {
  update: function(item) {
    this.el.setAttribute(item.name, "something");
  }
});
```

Directive name must be prefixed with `v-` in html. Object provided as value (`"item"`) is passed to `update` function of the directive.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzac8u23/2/)